# Can we have both Load Balancer and Reverse Proxy in the architecture

Tags: reverse-proxy, load-balancing

I read many articles regarding LoadBalancer and Reverse proxy and understood them individually. I know when we should keep what, load balancer when there are multiple servers basically with same content and when we are expanding and reverse proxy for many things like compression, security and hiding internal server info, but i think both routes the traffic as we want.

So usually do we have both loadBalancer and ReverseProxy in the architecture or do we have only 1 of them based on the need ? And if we have both, is load balancer placed between reverse proxy and application servers ?

Answer (score 2):

A load balancer is a specific use case of a reverse proxy where the reverse proxy is configured to direct traffic to (one of) multiple backend servers.

Comment: To clarify: we have a site with a limited number of IP addresses available. Here we use an HAProxy pair (active/passive) as a reverse proxy to present multiple services over the same IP/port combination. In another use case we have a similar HAProxy pair load balancing inbound user traffic across multiple identical web servers. The same product solves both use cases.